# Как перекинуть данные в HTML таблицу? Не могу перекинуть данные с тегов в таблицу(

Tags: javascript

```
var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();

xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function () {

    if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {

        GetNeededData(this);
    }
};

xmlhttp.open("GET", "http://api.worldweatheronline.com/premium/v1/weather.ashx?key=293fde5989a044348ad180530172204&q=Kremenchuk&format=xml&num_of_days=5", true);

xmlhttp.send();

function GetNeededData(xml) {
    var xmlDoc = xml.responseXML; 


    var temp_C = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("temp_C");
    document.write(temp_C[0].textContent ) 

    var temp_F = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("temp_F");
    document.write( temp_F[0].textContent)

    var windspeedKmph = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("windspeedKmph");
    document.write( windspeedKmph[0].textContent )   

}
```

Comment: Метод [`document.write()`](https://learn.javascript.ru/document-write) работает только пока HTML-страница находится в процессе загрузки. Я как-то не вижу записи в таблицу... Может быть приведете весь блок кода и опишете более детально, что у вас именно получилось, где у вас ошибка и что вы хотите увидеть.

Comment: Там данные берутся из XML файла

Comment: Короче говоря это парсинг )

Answer (score 0):

Немного модифицировал ваш код в сниппет, в котором видно, что после вызова `open` значение `this.readyState = 1`, а после `send` значение `this.readyState = 4`, но после вызова `send` падает ошибка `'Access-Control-Allow-Origin'` (это логично и ожидаемо):

```js
var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();

xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {

  console.log(this.readyState); 
  console.log(this.status);

  if (this.readyState == 4) {
    GetNeededData(this);
  }
};

xmlhttp.open("GET", "");
xmlhttp.send();

function GetNeededData(xml) {
  document.write(1);
  document.write(2);
  document.write(3);
}
```

Увы, так как падает ошибка, связанная с отсутствием доступа `'Access-Control-Allow-Origin'` или со смешанным контентом - не могу полностью протестировать ваш код. Но все же, дам ответ, который поможет. Добавил два вывода в консоль:

```
console.log(this.readyState); 
console.log(this.status);
```

Чтобы узнать, какой статус ответа на запрос и текущее состояние объекта `XMLHttpRequest`. Про статусы и все его плюшки можно почитать тут:

- [XMLHttpRequest](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest)
- [XMLHttpRequest.onreadystatechange](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/onreadystatechange)
- [XMLHttpRequest.readyState](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/readyState)

С точки зрения кода - все в порядке. Но для уверенности нужно убедиться, что не падает ошибка `Access-Control-Allow-Origin`, к примеру.  К какому выводу прихожу, добавьте как и я вывод в консоль, убедитесь, что статус ответа на запрос и текущее состояние объекта `XMLHttpRequest` соответствуют вашим ожиданиям:

```
this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200
```

Убедитесь, что в переменных получены данные (можно также, через `console.log`):

```
var temp_C = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("temp_C");
var temp_F = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("temp_F");
var windspeedKmph = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("windspeedKmph");
```

Также, убедитесь, что вам нужен метод [document.write()](https://learn.javascript.ru/document-write), который работает только пока HTML-страница находится в процессе загрузки.